# Использование готовой БД используя ROOM

Tags: android, android-room

Связанные вопросы:

1. Как использовать готовую БД, которая лежит в `assets` через `Room`?
2. Эта готовая БД содержит две таблицами. В каждой таблице по 50 тысяч записей. Рационально ли использовать `Room`  таким количеством записей для вывода в `RecyclerView`? Не будет тормозов?

Comment: насчёт большого количества записей - [используйте PagedListAdapter](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/27-course/architecture-components/542-urok-14-paging-library-chast-1.html)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/

Comment: Относительно первого вопроса. По умолчанию - никак. При каждом запуске приложения нужно проверять, существует ли бд по дефолтному для Room пути, и если нет - то руками копировать свою заполненную бд из ассетов.

Comment: А по первому вопросу есть ли какие-то готовые решения?

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263891/how-to-use-room-persistence-library-with-pre-populated-database
Лично я просто копирую "руками", как в предпоследнем ответе по ссылке.